# asp.net mvc autocomplete using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jquery-ui

I know that my question as already post in the forum, but i found no working solution. I am sure that i am doing something wrong but i am unable to find.

here is a test code who work and return me a list from the datatable

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub ObtientNomsRestaurants()
    Dim q = From c In dal.ObtientNomsRestaurants() 'As IQueryable of Resto
    For Each resto In q
        Console.WriteLine(resto.Nom)
    Next
End Sub
```

now in my controller, i call the dal method and try to return all element from my datatable column "Nom" that start with the parameter "Prefix"

```
<HttpPost>
    Public Function TagSearch(Prefix As String) As JsonResult
        Dim q = From c In dal.ObtientNomsRestaurants().Where(Function(m) m.Nom.StartsWith(Prefix)).Select(Function(m) New With {.Name = m.Nom}).ToList
        Return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

To finish in my view, i have an input textbox with "tags" as id
and this autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/TagSearch",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit:
So now i edit my controller and this is working

```
<HttpPost>
    Public Function TagSearch(Prefix As String) As JsonResult
        'Dim ObjList = dal.ObtientTousLesRestaurants()

        Dim ObjList As New List(Of Resto)() From {
            New Resto() With {.Id = 4, .Nom = "Latur"},
            New Resto() With {.Id = 5, .Nom = "Mumbai"},
            New Resto() With {.Id = 6, .Nom = "Pune"},
            New Resto() With {.Id = 7, .Nom = "Delhi"},
            New Resto() With {.Id = 8, .Nom = "Dehradun"},
            New Resto() With {.Id = 9, .Nom = "Noida"},
            New Resto() With {.Id = 10, .Nom = "New Delhi"}
        }
        Dim Nom = (From N In ObjList Where N.Nom.StartsWith(Prefix) Select New With {N.Nom})
        Return Json(Nom, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

but if i use the dal method to get database data, its not working. In both way, ObjList is a List Of Resto.

Comment: Please can you tell us the behaviour that you are looking for that isn't happening?

Comment: I am new in vb, the behavior that i am looking for is a textbox field with autocompletion of restaurant name. i have a class Resto where the restaurant name is Nom. and what i have is a textbox without any autocompletion or error

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see that there is data being returned from your VB method?

Comment: Yes, Prefix value = "L"; TagSearch value is Nothing and q value is nothing too

Comment: you can download the project from here [link](https://mega.nz/#!ypxUhDrS!Ob4AUfYK2ENGbsEfgYT3o_2obDgSbdkZQrT2L2-vmNI), just change connection string. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem who was in the connectionString
see [Solution here](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/autocompletion-asp-net-mvc)